# manage the customization code when porting android to a customer MIPS device

Tags: android, git, porting, repository

We want to port Android to our MIPS device, and are using the following code as the starting point.

```
$../repo init -u git://public.mipsandroid.com/mips/platform/manifest.git -b mips-froyo
```

And, definitely we need to do some customize work and even need to change some code in the framework. The question is how should we manage this changes in terms of SCM,  using git and repo?

Two options come to my mind but i don't if they are feasible and how to achieve it if they do make sense.

- branch out git://public.mipsandroid.com/mips/platform/manifest.git, so check out code using:

  $../repo init -u git://public.mipsandroid.com/mips/platform/manifest.git -b mips-froyo-xxx-company
- write a complete different manifest.git, similar to what [rowbot](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android_am389x_build_procedure) has done

  $ ~/bin/repo init -u git://gitorious.org/rowboat/manifest.git -m rowboat-froyo-am389x.xml

Anther questions is : how to write a `manifest.git`? Is the purpose of `mainifest.git` is  the same as the [`configure spec`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/r_mstrshp_rqst_config_spec.htm) in clearcase, pulling/fetching different branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer my self.

Suppose we have created a branch for bionic at  https://pierrchen@github.com/pierrchen/platform_bionic.git , aiming at do some customization work. Except the bionic library, everything else should be the same as what  mips-froyo will provide.

Here is how we can get the all repository:

```
repo init -u https://github.com/pierrchen/androidManifest

repo sync
```

Check out the default.xml, and notice following lines

```
<remote name="trident"
  fetch="https://github.com/pierrchen/"/>

<project path="bionic" name="platform_bionic" remote="trident" revision="master"/>
```

These lines in the manifests(default.xml) will direct the `repo` to get the `bionic` project from `remote` trident at the `version` "master". Every other projects will be get from remote `mipesea` at revision/branch `mips-froyo`. (see following lines in the default.xml)

```
 <remote name="mipsea"
           fetch="git://public.mipsandroid.com/mips" />

  <default revision="mips-froyo"
           remote="mipsea" />
```

To understand how to write/edit an `manifest` , just `repo help manifest`.